# kubernetes cert-manager failing with certificate chain is malformed or broken

Tags: kubernetes, cert-manager

I have setup cert-manager to sign the certificate with the private ca issuer. the private CA secret is setup correctly and before adding to the TLS secret i have verified the chain with OpenSSL verify command and they all verify to the root correctly. But when the same is done with cert-manager, the certificate is not signed and i get the error "    Message:                 The certificate request has failed to complete and will be retried: Error signing certificate: certificate chain is malformed or broken"

Here is the yaml for the cert issuer

```
   apiVersion: cert-manager.io/v1
   kind: ClusterIssuer
   metadata:
    name: my-ca-issuer
    namespace: default
   spec:
   ca:
      secretName: my-tls-secret
   ---
   apiVersion: cert-manager.io/v1
   kind: Certificate
   metadata:
     name: cert-test
     namespace: default
   spec:
     secretName: my-tls-secret
   issuerRef:
     name: my-ca-issuer
     kind: ClusterIssuer
   commonName: cert-test.com
   renewBefore: 12h # Renew the certificate when it's 12 hours from expiration
```

my-tls-secret is in the cert-manager namespace

the ca issuer verifies correctly

```
  kubectl get clusterissuers -o wide
NAME                        READY   STATUS                AGE
my-ca-issuer            True    Signing CA verified   27h
```

the my-tls secret was created using this command

```
 kubectl create secret generic my-tls-secret --from-file=tls.crt=cert-chain.pem --from-file=tls.key=myca.key --from-file=ca.crt=ca-chain.pem -n cert-manager
```

Any clues on why the chain is malformed with cert-manager whereas openssl verify doesnt have any issue with the chain

```
openssl crl2pkcs7 -nocrl -certfile ca-chain.pem | openssl pkcs7 -print_certs -noout

subject=C = US, ST = TX, L = Austin, O = org, CN = app-TLS-Sub-CA
issuer=C = US, ST = TX, L = Austin, O = org, CN = Issuing-Sub-CA

subject=C = US, ST = TX, L = Austin, O = org, CN = Issuing-Sub-CA
issuer=C = US, ST = TX, L = Austin, O = org, CN = Root

subject=C = US, ST = TX, L = Austin, O = org, CN = Root
issuer=C = US, ST = TX, L = Austin, O = org, CN = Root
```

Comment: SO is for programming questions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [your comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77533976/kubernetes-cert-manager-failing-with-certificate-chain-is-malformed-or-broken#comment136714285_77547008), the issue persists even after ensuring the correct order and concatenation of the certificates.

```bash
[ Kubernetes Cluster ]
         |
   [ cert-manager ]
         | \
         |  [ Increased Log Verbosity ]
         |
[ my-ca-issuer ClusterIssuer ]
         | \
         |  [ Check CA Permissions ]
         |
[ my-tls-secret (CA secret) ]
         | \
         |  [ Verify Certificate Chain Formatting ]
         |
[ cert-test Certificate ]
         |
   [ CertificateRequest Debugging ]
```

While OpenSSL is able to verify the chain, [`cert-manager`](https://github.com/cert-manager/cert-manager#cert-manager) in the Kubernetes context might interpret it differently. That could be due to how `cert-manager` handles certificate parsing.
Consider using a tool like [`kubectl describe`](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubectl/kubectl-commands#describe) on the `Certificate` and `CertificateRequest` resources to get more clues.

```bash
kubectl describe certificate cert-name -n default
kubectl describe certificaterequest -n default
kubectl describe clusterissuer my-ca-issuer
```

Sometimes, certificate files may contain hidden characters or formatting issues not easily visible. Make sure the PEM files do not contain any extraneous characters or incorrect line endings. You can use tools like `cat -v` or a text editor with hidden character visibility to inspect the files.

Make sure the CA represented by `my-tls-secret` has the necessary permissions to sign certificates. Some CAs might be restricted to only sign certain types or levels of certificates. That is particularly relevant since you have multiple levels in your CA hierarchy.

Increase the log verbosity of `cert-manager` to get more detailed information about what is happening during the signing process.

```bash
kubectl get deployments -n cert-manager
kubectl edit deployment <cert-manager-deployment-name> -n cert-manager

spec:
  containers:
  - args:
    - --v=4  # This sets log verbosity to level 4
    ...
```

Just in case, the depth of your certificate chain might be causing issues. While not common, some systems have limits on the chain depth they can process. If possible, test with a simpler chain (fewer levels) to see if the issue persists.

Comment: Thank you! You reminded me to check one of the missing identifiers in the certificate property.. I had the CA:True but the key usage was not set to Digital Signing. Once i added that, it worked correctly. It would have been great if the Cert-manager and the describer certificate commands gave any remote hint of that! But thanks to you, it worked correctly now!

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the issue might be related to the format or content of the certificate chain in the my-tls-secret secret. You should ensure the chain in tls.crt is correctly ordered and contains all necessary intermediate certificates.

Try concatenating your certificates in the correct order: your leaf certificate first, then the intermediates (if any), and the root certificate last. Then update the my-tls-secret with the correctly ordered chain.

Like this:

```
kubectl create secret generic my-tls-secret --from-file=tls.crt=combined-chain.pem --from-file=tls.key=myca.key --namespace=cert-manager
```

Then combine the certificates:

```
cat leaf-cert.pem intermediate-cert.pem root-cert.pem > combined-chain.pem
```

Let me know how this goes!

Comment: Yes I have tried this way of creating the secret before as well and i still get the same error. whether i specify the ca.crt or everything combined. And in either case the openssl verify works right

Comment: I have leaf, issuing, intermediate and root - 3 more levels from leaf